# Round up a Math::BigFloat number

Tags: perl, rounding

From what I understand reading the documentation of [`Math::BigFloat`](http://search.cpan.org/~pjacklam/Math-BigInt-1.997/lib/Math/BigFloat.pm), the following should be the code to round a number up, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Math::BigFloat;

my $x = Math::BigFloat->new('2.3');
$x->ffround(0, '+inf');
print "$x\n"; # -> 2
```

What should I do in order to always round the number *up* and, e.g., in this example get the number `3` as output.

Comment: What is the second argument to `ffround` supposed to do? The documentation does not mention it.

Comment: From the linked documentation: All rounding functions take as a second parameter a rounding mode from one of the following: 'even', 'odd', '+inf', '-inf', 'zero', 'trunc' or 'common'.

Comment: Aha! `$x->bceil()` does work as I expected. Still, would be nice if someone can clarify the use of rounding modes in `ffround`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rounding mode only affects the behaviour if rounding from exactly halfway between two possible results:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Math::BigFloat;

my $n = Math::BigFloat->new('2.5');

print $n->copy->ffround(1, 'zero');           # 2
print $n->copy->ffround(1, '+inf');           # 3
print $n->copy->ffround(1, 'odd');            # 3
print $n->copy->ffround(1, 'even');           # 2
```

What you want is `bceil`:

```
my $m = Math::BigFloat->new('2.3');

print $m->copy->bceil();                      # 3
```